# How to scale image without corrupt the ratio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would rescale the image, but I cannot find a way to do this.

Here is the code

```dart
return Column(
      // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(slider[idx].imageURL!),
                ),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
```

**current view**

[image: current view]

**target view**

[image: target view]

Comment: Can you include demo image link to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image widgets have a scale property you can use to make the image bigger or smaller: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageInfo/scale.html.

From there you can specify the desired [aspect ratio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html)
or use alignment (like you have) along with setting height and width to manually set the image size.

More about adjusting image sizes https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-display-and-adjust-images-from-assets

Comment: actually all the images are 16:9 aspect ratio and I don't want to change. I want only cutout any images right and left side and make vertical bigger images

Comment: To make the vertical bigger, use the [scale property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageInfo/scale.html).

To cutout the right and left side, since you already have the centered alignment you can just set the width of the element to the size you want.

Here's more info: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-display-and-adjust-images-from-assets

Comment: I update the answer based on your comment. The "without corrupt the ratio" part of the title mislead me. It might be worth removing that.